# Is it possible to animate collection of objects that form a whole object that parts of are already animated with armature?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

In this particular case i have a gun (collection of meshes) that parts of are rigged like trigger, shell ejector and top part shifting back. I want to add a recoil and tried selecting all the objects from a 'gun' collection and then keying rotation but parts shifted location somehow and everything broke.
How would i go about doing this the good way?

[image]

After trying to rotate along one axis: (doesn't even rotate)
[image: oops]

E: I found some semi/very helpful comment [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/im-needing-a-tutorial-on-how-to-animate-rig-a-gun/538248/3)

> I took a look at your model. If I was going to rig this gun, I would use 4 bones: a trigger bone and a clip bone which are both children of a gun body bone (all remaining vertices) which is in turn a child of a master bone. The only animation that the master bone is used for is the recoil; all other animations are keyframed using the other bones (reload, put away, aim down sights, etc.). I hope that makes sense.

So looks like i need to make a master bone and attach the rest of the stuff to it and hope it will work somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E: I found some semi/very helpful comment [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/im-needing-a-tutorial-on-how-to-animate-rig-a-gun/538248/3)

> I took a look at your model. If I was going to rig this gun, I would use 4 bones: a trigger bone and a clip bone which are both children of a gun body bone (all remaining vertices) which is in turn a child of a master bone. The only animation that the master bone is used for is the recoil; all other animations are keyframed using the other bones (reload, put away, aim down sights, etc.). I hope that makes sense.

So looks like i need to make a master bone and attach the rest of the stuff to it and hope it will work somehow

Added new armature, selected all objects including armatures, ctrl-P then Parent-> 'Armature with automatic weights' and it sort of worked i think. Also the problem was i was using parent to object and then sort of manually adding armature modifier to meshes and selecting armature because it seemed to work.But i fixed some stuff by 'reparenting' children of master node

Comment: for this kind of obects, parent With Empty Groups seems better, then you just need to assign the meshes you want to the vertex groups you want